# doesn't load image palette in PAL0 -> VDP_setPalette(PAL0,sprite_sonic.palette->data)

Tags: c, sonic

Decided to look into the SGDK. I wanted to add a Sonic's sprite to the screen, but something went wrong. Sonic's sprite loads but not in his palette. When loading, the PAL0 palette is used, in which the default colors remain (although I kind of changed them).
Here is a photo with a problem -> [sonic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgvs7.png).
This photo shows that Sonic is Black and White, and that PAL0 has not changed.
Here is the code:

```
#include <genesis.h>
#include "sprites.h"

Sprite* my_sprite_sonic;

int main()
{
    VDP_setBackgroundColor(40);
    VDP_setScreenWidth320();

    SPR_init();

    VDP_setPalette(PAL0,sprite_sonic.palette->data);
    
    my_sprite_sonic = SPR_addSprite(&sprite_sonic, 0, 0, TILE_ATTR(PAL0, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE));

    while(TRUE)
    {
        SPR_update();
        SYS_doVBlankProcess();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I'm being stupid, I apologize in advance. New to SGDK. I googled the question but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of
`VDP_setPalette(PAL0,sprite_sonic.palette->data);`
you need to use
`PAL_setPalette(PAL0, sonic_sprite.palette->data, DMA);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).